How to avoid shower cord damage from brief hot water flow after shutoff hot before cold taps?
My shower cable with metallic covering is leaking and I suspect damage from temporary hot water flow even though hot water tap is closed before cold water tap.
Is it possible brief hot water damage the plastic cord inside metallic covering? How to avoid such damage?

I will assume you mean the shower hose with plastic tubing inside a metallic covering.  If so, it should be made to handle hot water.  If leaking one of joints/rubber washers should be the problem or the tubing itself.

Upvote to crip659, for deciphering what the OP was talking about.

I seriously doubt that any leaking is caused by brief hot water flow. Most plastic/rubber tubing has at rating of 160 degrees F and continuous duty. You can't really avoid the damage but you might be able to fix it by replacing the washers at both ends. If that doesn't work, you can probably replace the entire hose at your home store or plumbing supply store.

Correct, not heat damage.  Not worth a whole new answer: common causes of leaks are 1) using teflon tape on a joint that has a rubber washer, which prevents the thing from tightening sufficiently for the washer to work, Buy a new hose and follow the instructions.  2) cracks in the "nuts", which are the ends of the hose and sometimes made of plastic.   Replace with a better one.  3) Missing washers.  4) Damaged washers, although in my experience shower hoses fail in other ways before their washers do, 5) Reverse threaded ball joint not tightened correctly 6) $2 hoses that leak no matter what.

I ended up replacing and also disconnecting new shower cord after each shower to avoid heat deteriorating rubber component of cord. I suspect hot water tap repair is needed but it is my landlord responsibility.

How does heat affect your hose differently if it is attached or not attached to the shower while it's off?
